# Reverse output of a command

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to get the reversed output from

```
git log --branches --graph --oneline
```

(Sadly, you can't pass `--reverse` to it, because it says it's incompatible with `--graph`.)

Is there a way to reverse the output of the command?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

On Linux, add [`| tac`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) at the end of your line.

Comment: Trivia (but it could be a way of remembering it): ['tac'](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) is the reverse of ['cat'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)).

Answer (score 16):

If you don't have [`tac`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) (like on Mac), you should be able to use `| tail -r` as explained [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114043/175942) on the sister site *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: Tail on ubuntu has neither -r or -R.

Comment: @Zitrax very possible. But then you have `tac` on Ubuntu and can use Cyru's answer.